# What roles did Yossei/Joseph I as governor and the house of David play in assisting Judas Maccabee and the rebels against the Seleucid empire?

Tags: king-david, greek, book-of-maccabees

Shalom, during the second century BCE, Seleucid ruled over Judea, and the Maccabees led a revolt against the imposition of Hellenism. They sought to restore Jewish independence and worship under the leadership of Judas Maccabee. How important were Yossei/Joseph I and the House of David in contributing resources, legitimacy, and manpower to the rebellion's success? What more can be learned about their roles from historical sources like Josephus or apocryphal writings?

Comment: The "religious" sources mostly knock the Maccabees for declaring themselves kings afterwards, rather than going with the time-honored division of power -- Davidic line are kings, Aaronic line are priests. The Hasmoneans tried to be both priests and kings and wound up doing a not-great job at either. As far as internal politics during the rebellion? You'd really have to consult a scholar of that period -- maybe someone like Malka Simkovich; you're not going to find a lot from those with just traditional religious education.

Comment: This winds up being so far afield from traditional religious sources that I'm torn as to whether to vote to close.

Comment: Who's "Yossei/Joseph I"?

Comment: From this it would seem that it was Joseph's son, Hyrcanus, who would have flourished during the revolt. I would think his fortunes would have been tied up with the Greeks and, if I were him, would favor their rule over that if the macabees. He was wasnt a ruler, only a tax farmer.https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/tobiads